# What's the role of unification in Coq's core type system?

Tags: coq, dependent-type, type-systems, theorem-proving, unification

When type checking proof terms, how does unification come into play after elaboration to the core language of Calculus of Inductive Constructions?

Specifically, when dealing with properties of equalities like transitivity and symmetry, I find it challenging to comprehend where the unification of variables occurs when proving statements like `forall x y, x = y -> y = x` by pattern matching on `refl x x`.

Additional context: I am aware that unification is necessary in the extended language of Coq, particularly when introducing existential variables and implicitly instantiating them. However, when reviewing the documentation on the core typing rules of Coq, I could not find any explicit mention of unification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple: there is no unification in the kernel.

In the particular case you mention, you can look at a proof term, which will look something like

```
fun x y (e : x = y) =>
  match e as e' in _ = y' return y' = x with
    | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end
```

I intentionally included the `return` clause: this is where the interesting things are happening. This clause binds multiple variable: one for each index of the inductive type (here, equality has one index, so there is one bound variable `y'`), and an extra one (here `e'`) for the scrutinee (the term matched on, here `e`). In each branch, these bound variables are replaced by the specific indices for the given constructor, and this constructor itself. For instance, for equality there is just one branch, where `y'` is replaced by `x` (and `e'` by `eq_refl`). If each branch type-check against its "specialized version" of the return clause, then the whole pattern-matching has a type obtained from the return clause by replacing the variable for the indices by the indices of the scrutinee, and the last on by the scrutinee itself.

All in all, this mechanism might look like unification, because it relates different instances of the same dependent type: the one in the branches, and the one of the whole pattern-matching. But while during elaboration the return clause can be inferred by Coq using unification (alleviating the user from giving it by hand), once a suitable one has been found there is no unification any more.

Comment: typo fix: `y'` should bind the index `y`, not `x`?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the typo? What sentence do you think is incorrect?

Comment: Here: "For instance, for equality there is just one branch, where y' is replaced by x (and e' by eq_refl)."

Comment: No, this is correct: in the branch, the indices are replaced by those of the constructor. In this case, `eq_refl : x = x`, and so `y'` is replaced by (the second) `x`. In some sense, the branches do not "know" about the type of the scrutinee. `y'` is replaced by `y` only in the type of the whole pattern-matching (here `y = x`).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. After reading through the Coq manual section on dependent pattern matching, I (may) have finally grasped the idea. It seems that the use of parameters and implicit arguments in the original Coq `eq` type may have made it challenging to comprehend the program. To assist others who may encounter similar difficulties, I have provided a more explicit version below. Thank you once again for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Meven has provided an excellent answer. I also find the description of dependent pattern matching in the Book "Certified Programming with Dependent Types" especially useful (The One Rule of Dependent Pattern Matching in Coq, http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.MoreDep.html).

As a supplement, here is a more explicit version of equality definition and some proof terms about its properties:

```
Module Dependent_pattern_matching.

  Context (A : Type).

  Inductive equal : A -> A -> Prop :=
    refl : forall x, equal x x.

  Definition eq_refl : forall x : A, equal x x :=
    fun x : A => refl x.

  Definition eq_sym : forall (x y : A) (H : equal x y), equal y x :=
    fun (x y : A) (H : equal x y) =>
      match H in (equal a b) return (equal b a) with
      | refl m => refl m
      end.

  Definition eq_trans : forall (x y z : A) (H1 : equal x y) (H2 : equal y z), equal x z :=
    fun (x y z : A) (H1 : equal x y) (H2 : equal y z) =>
      match H1 in (equal a b) return (equal b z -> equal a z) with
      | refl n => fun H : equal n z => H
      end H2.

End Dependent_pattern_matching.
```

Comment: Beware: the equality you give here is slightly different from the one of Coq's standard library, for which the first argument of type `A` is also a parameter. That is, in your code it would be `Inductive equal (x : A) : A -> Prop := refl : equal x x.`. The two are quite similar (and actually equivalent in the logical sense), but they give slightly different induction principles/dependent pattern-matching (their `return` will not have the same bound variables).